# I cannot upload files > 100K

Tags: php, html, fedora, lamp

I am not able to upload files larger than 100KB.  Uploading multiple smaller files is OK.   This is **LAMP** running on **Fedora 27**.

Here are the pertinent code snippets.  The return value is "2", which I believe means that the file is too big. I've already set and adjusted the usual suspects in php.ini.  I am not getting to `$mail->AddAttachment` so I don't expect that it is a phpmailer issue.

**Front End Code :**

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"\>
      <input name="file_arr[]" id='userfiles' type="file" multiple="multiple"/ >
      <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Send' />
```

**Back End Code :**

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
.
    foreach ($_FILES["file_arr"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
                    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
                        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file_arr"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                        $fname = $_FILES["file_arr"]["name"][$key];
                        $mail->AddAttachment($tmp_name, $fname);
                        $fcnt++;
                    } else {
                        return($error);
                    }
               }
```

Comment: Or didn't restart apache or fpm or whatever you have there.

Comment: "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form." See [Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). In what way have you modified php.ini? Are the changes reflected in the output from [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)?

Comment: The MAX_FILE_SIZE directive is not on the form.  I did add it in an attempt to fix but removed afterwards.  Here is stuff from phpinfo:

Comment: upload_max_filesize => 50M => 50M  post_max_size => 80M => 80M

Comment: How many files are you uploading? What is the total size of all the files?

Comment: I've done as many as 4 small files at one time; each about 60K.  The failure occurs using a single file of > 100K.  I've tried a couple different files over 100K with the same result

Answer (score 0):

**Adjust php.ini**
You need to check php.ini to see what your max file upload size is set to. You can adjust `memory_limit, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size` variables accordingly.

**Get php.ini Location**
To find your php.ini, run phpinfo() and echo the results: `echo phpinfo();`

You may or may not need to echo phpinfo().

Comment: All of this has been done.  Here are the pertinent lines from phpinfo(): upload_max_filesize => 50M => 50M; post_max_size => 80M => 80M; memory_limit => 128M => 128M.  The issue still exists.